# Как парсить отрицательное значение?

Tags: java

Проблема заключается в том, что при вводе отрицательного числа выскакивает ошибка NumberFormatException: For input string: "-". Что необходимо изменить что-бы "-" являлся частью цифры, а не отдельным символом.

```
 private List<IntermediateValues> separateDividentValuesToDivide() {
    String[] dividentToArray = String.valueOf(divident).split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < dividentToArray.length; i++) {
        inprogressQuotient.append(dividentToArray[i]);
        int quotient = Integer.parseInt(inprogressQuotient.toString());
        divideBySteps(quotient, i, dividentToArray.length);
    }
    return changeableValues;
}
```

and main.class code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int divident = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int divider = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    DivisionSteps steps = new DivisionSteps(divident, divider);
    DivisionConstructor constructor = steps.arithmetics();

    DrawDivision draw = new DrawDivision();
    List<String> complete = draw.makeFormat(constructor);
    for (int j = 0; j < complete.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(complete.get(j));
    }
```

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Если у Вас проблемы с обаботкой ввода, то надо показать пример ввода, который вызывает ошибку, и пример ввода, который работает.

Comment: `String[] dividentToArray = String.valueOf(divident).split("");` -- этот код, как понимаю, вернет массив односимвольных строк. Зачем тут использовать массив строк, если можно использовать `toCharArray`, или вовсе `charAt(int pos)`? Валидацию лучше делать сразу после ввода, в саму функцию передавать числа, и быть уверенным, что тут не будет проблем с не-числом.

Answer (score 1):

```
int quotient = Integer.parseInt(inprogressQuotient.toString());
```

Что в этот момент находится в `inprogressQuotient`? Знак "минус"? Это не целое число, так что все правильно.